# how to use several data.frames in "for" loop in R

Tags: r

I have such problem:

There are several dataframes in my global environment, which have same number of columns, same classes of columns and etc. I know, that they are named like `df_1`, `df_4`, `df_123123`, `df_3456` and etc

So, i'd like to bind them together using `bind_rows()` function in "For" loop.

I tried to do this, but got an error

```
for (i in ls()[grepl("df",ls())]){
    Final_df<- bind_rows(Final_df,i)
}
```

But in my loop i variable becomes a character string, not dataframe, how can i fix it?

Comment: wow! that's i'm looking for, thank u!

Comment: `bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern="df")))` ( or also `do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern="df")))` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comment ?get should help you. 
You noticed already your "i" variable becomes a string variable.
So you would have the get the values of a variable based on the variables name.

Example:

```
a=1
get("a")
```